# Infinite Loop on Simple Game

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with a simple game in JavaScript which loops through 'hits' on a dragon until the dragon is killed.

The game is working well, however if the result is a miss i.e. `youHit = 0` then the script gets stuck in an infinite loop. I know the infinite loop is caused by the final else statement where `slaying = true` (if false then the game stops and the script must be run again). My question is how can I loop through both misses and hits without getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
var slaying = true
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1)
var totalDamage = 0
var health = 4

while(slaying) {

    if (youHit) {
        totalDamage += damageThisRound
        console.log("You hit for " + totalDamage + " damage");
        if (health <= 0) {
            console.log('You slayed the dragon!')
            slaying = false;
        } else {
            health -= totalDamage
            if (health <= 0) {
                slaying = false;
                console.log('You slayed the dragon!')
            }
            else {
            slaying = true;
            }
        }

    } else {
        console.log("You missed!");
        slaying = true;
    }

    console.log('Health: ' + health)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not recalculating the hit/miss boolean inside of the loop. So you will either always hit or always miss. If you always miss, this results in an infinite loop.

Move `var youHit = . . .` into your `while (slaying)` loop.